# Has anyone added iAds to an existing app that's already on the app store? If so, how do you do this?

Tags: xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, iad

I assumed you could just add a banner by simply updating it but I saw something in iTunes Connect that made me think I might need to do something else to make the ads run correctly.  Any insight is much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just build it with ads and submit it for review with new binary.